# Unlock bootloader on Dell Venue 10 5050

Tags: unbricking, tablet, bootloader, bootloader-lock, dell

I have a bricked Dell tablet that doesn't boot and also a has locked bootloader (Secure Boot: Enable). I've made a full partition dd backup, but now I cannot flash it via fastboot supposedly because of the locked bootloader. I obtained root before making the backup and so this backup seems to be unsigned, as they said me [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=74492332).

I tried to unlock via `fastboot oem unlock` but it throws

> > FAILED (remote: unknown OEM command)

Command `fastboot flashing unlock` doesn't work as well.

This tablet [has BIOS](https://img.xda-cdn.com/P4Rh0LYCwxOpsFLxokYskreGsew=/https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2F9e7TZjz.jpg) but it doesn't have option for disabling Secure Boot.

I found [this instruction](http://opensource.dell.com/releases/Venue_10_5050_Baytrail-CR/developer-edition/OSS_Venue10_5050.docx) how to disable Secure Boot, but I wasn't able to fulfill it, 'cause I got **flash_cmds error** while flashing osloader.

Is there any chance to unlock bootloader or fix it some other way?